# Deploying a Sales Cadence to another org

Tags: deployment, change-set, sales-cadence, high-velocity-sales

I would like to know if it is possible to deploy an active sales cadence to another org using outbound changeset or if the only possible way is to create the same sales cadence in the other org?

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that it's not currently possible to move a sales cadence (active or inactive) between orgs using change sets.

The sales cadence is created / managed through a salesforce UI, but what you're building isn't actually Salesforce metadata. That's why it isn't exposed as an option in the change set components menu.

It looks like for now the only way to manage cadences between environments is by manually re-creating them. Also keep in mind the cadence cannot be modified once it's been activated. It has to be cloned into a new cadence all together.

Comment: I don't have access to High Velocity Sales to dig into this, but there is a metadata type called `ActionCadence` that is accessible in the [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_actioncadence.htm) that seems to represent Sales Cadences. Perhaps change sets don't expose this object (always tough to say with some of these Salesforce add-ons) but it should definitely be possible to reference them programmatically and through the API.